# How to display CRUD views in a jquery dialog model form, or in a bootstrap popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

```js
<script src="jquery-js">
 $("._detailsInfo").click( function () {
            var Id = $(this).attr('Id');
            $.ajax({
                "url": "/Test/Details/"+Id,
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#myModal').modal(options);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
@model BOL3.tbl_Appoiment_Diary

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Details</h4>
            <hr />
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<td>
                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |*@
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn btn-xs _detailsInfo" id=" '+ item.ID +' ">Details</button> |
                            @Html.Partial("_Details", new BOL3.tbl_Appoiment_Diary())
                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "_Details", new { @class = "_detailsInfo", id = "'+item.ID+'" }) |*@                                  
                        </td>
```

Can anyone help me with this. Please keep in mind that I'm quite new working with Javascript and Jquery so any help is greatly appreciated. I tryied different methods from multiple websites but nothing worked. Here are some of the websites that I tryed:

[jquery-dialog-with-aspnet-mvc](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/crud-operations-using-jquery-dialog-entity-framework-and-aspnet-mvc) , [jquery-dialog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/092589/implementing-modal-pop-up-in-mvc-application/), and many others, but nothing seems to work.

Here is what i tryed until now:

```
public ActionResult Details(int Id)
     {
         BOL3.tbl_Appoiment_Diary appd = new BOL3.tbl_Appoiment_Diary();
         appd = db.tbl_Appoiment_Diary.Find(Id);
         return PartialView("_Details", appd);
     }
```

this is the controller part.

```js
<script src="jquery-js">
        //$(function () {
        //    $("#dialog").dialog({
        //        autoOpen: false,
        //        modal: true,
        //        title: "Details"
        //    });
        //    $("#AppoimentDiary .details").click(function () {
        //        var ID = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
        //        $.ajax({
        //            type: "POST",
        //            url: "/Test/Details/",
        //            data: '{ID: "' + ID  + '"}',
        //            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //            dataType: "html",
        //            success: function (response) {
        //                $('#dialog').html(response);
        //                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        //            },
        //            failure: function (response) {
        //                alert(response.responseText);
        //            },
        //            error: function (response) {
        //                alert(response.responseText);
        //            }
        //        });
        //    });
        //});




        //$(document).ready(function () {
        //    $("#btnCreate").click(function () {
        //        InitializeDialog($("#testdialog"));
        //        $("#testdialog").dialog("open");
        //    });

        //    function InitializeDialog($element) {
        //        $.dialog({
        //            autoOpen: false,
        //            width: 400,
        //            resizable: true,
        //            draggable: true,
        //            title: "Appointments",
        //            model: true,
        //            show: 'slide',
        //            closeText: 'x',
        //            dialogClass: 'alert',
        //            closeOnEscape: true,
        //            open: function (event, ui) {
        //                $element.load('/Test/Add');
        //            },
        //            close: function () {
        //                $(this).dialog('close');
        //            }
        //        });
        //    }
        //});



        //$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        //$(document).ready(function () {
        //    $(".openPopup").live("click", function (e) {
        //        e.preventDefault();
        //        $("<div></div><p>")
        //        .addClass("dialog")
        //        .attr("id", $(this)
        //        .attr("data-dialog-id"))
        //        .appendTo("body")
        //        .dialog({
        //            title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
        //            close: function () { $(this).remove(); },
        //            modal: true,
        //            height: 250,
        //            width: 900,
        //            left: 0
        //        })
        //        .load(this.href);
        //    });
        //    $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
        //        e.preventDefault();
        //        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        //    });
        //});

        @*var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Test")';
        $('selector').load(url, { id: 1 });*@
               
    </script>
```

```html
 @Html.ActionLink("Det", "Details", new { id = item.ID, @class = "data-toggle = 'modal' data-target = '#myModal' " }) |
 
 <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    </div>
    
</div>
@*<div id='myModal' class='modal'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="myModalContent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="jquery-js">
    var TeamDetailPostBackURL = '/Test/Details';
    $(function () {
        $(".anchorDetail").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var $buttonClicked = $(this);
            var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
            var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { "Id": id },
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal(options);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Loading the data is not possible!");
                }
            });
        });
        $("#closbtn").click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>*@

@*<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:aqua">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Ada New</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Url.Action("/Test/Details")
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:aqua">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dissmiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>*@
```

Any help on this topic is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:

This is the index button, the script is from your answer:

in the same index view, and here is the partial view:

Comment: Can you update your question ? Remove all the commented and unnecessary codes. Just keep the partial view code, action method and js code for details data (I mean to load Modal).

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: Remove this src="jquery-js" from your script tag. Bdw your Details action method should present inside Test Controller. Or else Now your code is fine. It should work properly. Remove @Html.ActionLink("Det", "Details", new { id = item.ID, @class = "data-toggle = 'modal' data-target = '#myModal' " }) |
 
 <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    </div>
    
</div> And  If u are testing in chrome, then right click -> inspect -> check the console whether u r getting any error or what ?

Comment: I chanced it to how you specified but still nothing. I when on inspect->console to view if there were any errors and there aren't any, it's just a warning about: "Invalid unquoted attribute value. Unquoted attribute values should not contain ("), ('), (<), (=), or (`).". I think that I will close this topic, and learn a bit more about it and then try again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, there is no need to call again **details** method from your modal body.

Create a modal inside partial view, and keep all your partial view HTML inside the modal body. And in top of your partial view, **add your modal reference**, like bellow,

```
@model Your_Project_Name.ModalFolderName.tbl_Appoiment_Diary

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-header">Details Info</div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    /*Here keep your all HTML to display details data*/
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Change or update the above HTML accordingly. And change the reference name with your project name and class name.

Create your Details button in your main view, like this,

```
<button class="btn btn-info _detailsInfo" id="'+item.ID+'"></Details>
```

While click this button call a jquery click function like bellow,

```
$("._detailsInfo").click(function () 
 {
  var Id = $(this).attr('Id');
  $.ajax({
        "url": "/Test/Details/"+Id,
        "type": "Get",
        "dataType": "html",
        success: function (response) {
                   $('#myModal').modal(options);
                   $('#myModal').modal('show');
                },
        failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
               }
           });
    });
```

Suppose your partial view name is _Details.cshtml. Then just render it inside your main view like this,(basically keep this bellow code before the **close tag** of **body** of your main view)

```
@Html.Partial("_Details", new tbl_Appoiment_Diary())
```

That's it! Hope it helps you.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I tried you answer, but when I access the button it doesn't redirect me to details partial view. Maybe I did something wrong but it's not working for me, but thank you for you answer.

Comment: What do u mean by "doesn't redirect me to details partial view" ? Do you want to show a partial view in Modal Popup in the same view or in a single new view ?

Comment: Sorry bad way of saying this, it doesn't open the popup

Comment: No the thing is that I want something like when I access the actionlink from index page to open the popup for (Details, Create and Edit View or partial view just like the link description that I gave at the beginning (first link or second)), but I don't know how.

Comment: Yah that is what I did for Details Popup Modal. Did u went through my complete answer ? Did u follow all the steps ? If yes, then where are you getting error ? After click the details button is it calling to your action method ? Put a break point and check..

Comment: The thing is that it does not display any error, but doesn't open the popup.

Comment: Let me Edit my question maybe you will see something I don't.

Comment: Did you put your Details HTML code inside Modal ?  Did you render your partial view in your main view(Index) like this @Html.Partial("_Details", new tbl_Appoiment_Diary()) ?? And first let me know, Is it calling to your Action method or not ? Put a break point in your action method and let me know...

Comment: I edited the question. That part "@Html.Partial("_Details", new tbl_Appoiment_Diary())" I didn't put in it, maybe this is why!

Comment: It's the same, nothing happens. Thanks for your help, I will try to research a little more to better understand this jquery dialog and popup thing. Thank you.